# How to escape characters inside variables in awk?

Tags: bash, awk, scripting, escape-characters

I'm trying to make a script that uses awk to get the recent file names from .config/okularrc and pipe them into dmenu, and back to awk to get the path for the name selected.
However, I'm getting an error that tells me that there is a character that should be escaped in the regex.
Okularrc file:

```
[Recent Files]
File1[$e]=$HOME/documents/med/oh/OH Lecture (12)_Lead Poisoning Summary.pdf
File2[$e]=$HOME/ug/Biochemistry/1. biochemistry of kidney.pdf
File3[$e]=$HOME/ug/Archives/3. UG-(mid+final)-WAREED.pdf
File4[$e]=$HOME/ug/Biochemistry/1. b)iochemistry of kidney.pdf
Name1[$e]=OH Lecture (12)_Lead Poisoning Summary.pdf
Name2[$e]=1. biochemistry of kidney.pdf
Name3[$e]=3. UG-(mid+final)-WAREED.pdf
Name4[$e]=1. b)iochemistry of kidney.pdf
```

the script I made:

```
#!/bin/bash

DEBUG=1

# Get the names of the files
names=$(awk -F'=' '/^Name/{print $2} ' ~/.config/okularrc)
[ $DEBUG == 1 ] && echo -e "[*] Names are:\n$names\n"


# Pass the names to dmenu and select a file
selected_name=$(echo "$names" | dmenu -l 10 -i -p "Select a recent file:")
[ $DEBUG == 1 ] && echo -e "[*] Selected name is:\n$selected_name\n"

# Get the path of the selected file
file_path=$(awk -v name="$selected_name" -F'=' '$2 ~ name "$" && /^File/ {print $2}' ~/.config/okularrc)
[ $DEBUG == 1 ] && echo -e "[*] File path is:\n${file_path}\n"


# Run Okular with the path of the file
okular "${file_path/'$HOME'/$HOME}"

# If history is zero just start okular; TODO add browser
#[ -z $names ] && okular && exit
```

and when i run this on files that have "(" it gives me this output:

```
[*] Names are:
1. b(iochemistry of kidney.pdf

[*] Selected name is:
1. b(iochemistry of kidney.pdf

awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=/home/anonymous/.config/okularrc FNR=1) fatal: invalid regexp: Unmatched ( or \(: /1. b(iochemistry of kidney.pdf$/
[*] File path is:
```

I'm new to awk and i want to learn more, your help would be much appreciated

Comment: You could consider using the string-based [index function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-index_0028_0029-function) instead of the regex-based `~`

Comment: Your other choice would be to escape all the regex special characters.

Comment: Thanks alot @steeldriver The index function solved it all, can i escape the regex chars inside a variable like i have here?

Comment: It would be possible to replace all `/` with `\/`, but that in itself would be hard to escape correctly (I would guess `\\/`). But for a generic regex that may contain any of `()[]{}?*+^$|`, the only viable option might be to escape *every* character by prefixing with `\\` (I think spurious escapes are ignored).

Comment: Given that the same info is yet in your tag "File" that you use anyway, why don't you pass the selected portion of that tag "File" to te selection tool ? The tag "Name" is superfluous because it contains information that is not sufficient to open the document anyway, and necessarily equal for the mapping to work !

Answer (score 0):

Replaced this line:

```
file_path=$(awk -v name="$selected_name" -F'=' '$2 ~ name "$" && /^File/ {print $2}' ~/.config/okularrc)
```

with this line:

```
file_path=$(awk -v name="$selected_name" -F'=' 'index($2,name) && /^File/ {print $2}' ~/.config/okularrc)
```

credits goes to @steeldriver

Comment: `index($2,name)` is not the string comparison equivalent of the regexp comparison `$2 ~ name "$"` as it'd say name `foo` matches $2 `foobar`, and your regexp comparison was already incomplete (didn't match at start of string). From your example, you just need `$2 == name`. Also, file names can contain `=` so you shouldn't be relying on using `=` as `FS` and selecting a field, $2, for this. There are other issues with your script too - ask a new question if you'd like help doing what you're trying to do robustly.